# What is the most efficient collection for accessing an object based on two key variants?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement a large cache of objects (up to 500000) and need to be able to access them in two different ways...

The key for each item is made up of three different strings; ItemNumber, PubCode and SizeCode. In some circumstances I'll be calling for a match on all three of those values to return a single object. In other cirumstances I'll be calling for a match on only ItemNumber and PubCode with a view to returning a collection of objects.

What is the best collection to use for this?

I've considered just using a generic list of object (of which all three of the key values are properties of) and using LINQ to query it, however I don't believe this is going to be the most performant way of doing this especially when you consider the size of the collection.

Any help will as always be appreciated!

Comment: None of the existing caching solutions address your needs?

Comment: is this read-only or do you expect to add items to this data structure at runtime?

Comment: Apologies, the cache will be readonly. It will be refreshed roughly every 5 minutes.

Comment: I am afraid you have to write your own collection and manage the addition and removal operations like in @Philips' answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many items are you likely to have for any ItemNumber / PubCode combination? If the answer is "reasonably few" then I would start off with a `Lookup<ItemNumberPubCode, Value>` (or a `Dictionary<ItemNumberPubCode, List<Value>>`) - so if you're asked to look up by just the two of them, you can get straight to all matches. If you're asked to look up by all three, you fetch all the matches of the first two really quickly, and then do an O(n) scan for any match by SizeCode.

(Here `ItemNumberPubCode` is a type encapsulating the `ItemNumber` and `PubCode`; this could be an anonymous type, a `Tuple<string, string>`, or a real type.)

If there can be *lots* of matches for a particular ItemNumber / PubCode combination, then you might want a `Dictionary<ItemNumberPubCode, Dictionary<string, Value>>` - that will let you efficiently search by all three, and from just two of them you can fetch the dictionaries and use the `Values` property to find all matching values for the pair.

Comment: A dictionary of dictionaries seems to be the right way forward methinks, although I'm intrigued with your use of Tuple... in terms of readonly performance how would that compare when used as a dictionary key compared to a concatenated string?

Comment: @JamesLaw: I wouldn't like to guess, to be honest - but a concatenated string has a problem, as { "Foo", "Bar" } ends up with the same key as  {"FooB", "ar" }. Of course you can add a delimiter yourself if you know that it won't occur in the keys. You might want to *consider* a custom struct with two string references as the key type (and override Equals/GetHashCode of course). As always, benchmark to determine the real cost.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way to do it using a Dictionary of Dictionaries.  Like Jon said, whether you need this depends on the data.

```
class TwoKeyDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, T>>
{
    public new IEnumerable<T> this[string key1]
    {
        get { return base[key1].Values; }
    }

    public T this[string key1, string key2]
    {
        get { return base[key1][key2]; }
    }

    public void Add(string key1, string key2, T item)
    {
        if (!base.ContainsKey(key1))
            base[key1] = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        base[key1].Add(key2, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can go and use a tree or hash structure for indexing (for example (Sorted)Dictionary) - in your case you would use three of them.
You just have to identify exactly what you need.

I don't know your scenario but I would guess that it would be sufficient to just cache based on one property and just use normal database-indizes (more or less the same as above) for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is read-only I'd make a non-collection class that houses two collections.

```
public class CacheOfManyObjects
{
    private Dictionary<string, ObjectsToBeCached> ObjectsByItemPubSize{get;set;}
    //You might want to replace the IEnumerable<> with a List<>
    // but that depends on implementation
    private Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ObjectsToBeCached>> ObjectsByItemPub{get;set;}

    public ObjectsToBeCached GetByItemPubSize(string tString);
    public IEnumerable<ObjectsToBeCached> GetByItemPub(string tString);
}
```

The objects would be added to each Dictionary. You will need additional logic to create the object cache, but there is no real reason to have just 1 collection, since the collections themselves are small.